# How do I test against an elements id value on a mouse over event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Wondering if someone could please help me understand how to test against the ID value of a element, in a mouse over event.  I assume I have to use 'this'.

the value I am getting for ID is "undefined"

```js
function mouseOver() {
  var e = $(this).attr("ID"); //need help with this bit
  if (e == ("row2012")) {
    alert(e)
  } else {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="x in Interruptions">
      <td id=row{{x.year}} onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
          {{x.year}}
      </td>
      <td>{{x.totalEvents}}</td>
      <td>{{x.customers}}</td>
      <td>{{x.avgDuration}}</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Your `mouseOver` function will receive an event object. The element that was moused over is `event.target`. So, with vanilla js, you could just do `const id = event.target.getAttribute('id');`

Comment: @JeremyHarris that's not true when using inline `onX` attributes, as the OP is. He could pass the event in, or even the id attribute value itself. A better approach would be to use unobtrusive event handlers, though.

Comment: I want to add to what @RoryMcCrossan said since the comment by @JeremyHarris has received so many erroneous upvotes. There is an important difference between the `onmouseover` *attribute* and the `onmouseover` *property* of an element. The attribute is set by HTML, the property is set by JavaScript. And they behave differently. The *attribute* is evaluated by the browser as a JavaScript statement. Its functions do not receive event objects. On the other hand the *property* is evaluated as an event listener function with the first argument being the event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the current dom element directly by passing `this` inside `onmouseover` & `onmouseout` functions like:

```
<td id=row{{x.year}} onmouseover="mouseOver(this)" onmouseout="mouseOut(this)">{{x.year}}</td>
```

and then access the element `id` in js code like:

```
function mouseOver(elem) {
  var e = elem.id;
  if (e == "row2012") {
    alert(e)
  } else {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: it's also possible to use `onmouseover="mouseOver(window.event)"` and than do
`function mouseOver(event) {
  var e = event.target.id;
  // ...
`

Comment: @NiklasE. using `window.event` would work, but isn't good practice. It should be avoided where possible

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Why should using `window.event` be avoided? Can you cite a source for that assertion?

Comment: Trying to find one for you, but in short it's support is patchy in Firefox versions and the only reason it exists is due to a legacy implementation in Internet Explorer that others only adopted to maintain compatibility. It was never intended as a standard to be used.

Comment: Actually, if you check the details on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) it advises: `You should avoid using this property in new code, and should instead use the Event passed into the event handler function. This property is not universally supported and even when supported introduces potential fragility to your code. Note: This property can be fragile, in that there may be situations in which the returned Event is not the expected value. In addition, Window.event is not accurate for events dispatched within shadow trees.`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for that reference. It looks like that means one should avoid using the onevent atrributes altogether and use the more modern `addEventListener` method.

Comment: That's a corollary, but also definitely the case. It's good practice to avoid those due to the Separation of Concerns principle.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave`, and pass the variable `x` to both:

```
<td id=row{{x.year}} ng-mouseenter ="mouseOver(x)" ng-mouseleave="mouseOut(x)">{{x.year}}</td>
```

Then in the functions, you can simply use:

```
$scope.mouseOver = function(item) {
  var id = `row${item.year}`
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the following inforamtion.

In your HTML pass this in the function mouseOver(this)

```html
<td id="1" onmouseover="mouseOver(this)" onmouseout="mouseOut(this)">2019</td>
```

Now in the function use following

```js
function mouseOver(ele) {
  var eleId = $(ele).attr("Id"); //need help with this bit
  if (eleId == "yourid") {
    alert(eleId)
  } else {
    alert(eleId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the `this` context is bound to the element. It is a misnomer to label it as `evt`. This confuses the way functons are evaluated in the `onmouseover` attribute and the way thay are evaluated  in the `onmouseover` property.

Answer (score 0):

### Use the `ng-mouse*` Directives

With the AngularJS framework, one should avoid the using the `onmouseover` attribute. Instead use the `ng-mouseover` directive. It is integrated with the AngularJS framework and evaluates expressions in the AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-mouseover Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover)
- AngularJS does not have an `ng-mouseout` Directive
- [AngularJS ng-mouseenter Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter)
- [AngularJS ng-mouseleave Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave)

---

### `ng-mouseover` with `ng-repeat` special variables

The `ng-repeat` directive creates child scopes with special variables set by the directive. One of them is `$index`.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in arr">
   <p ng-mouseover="mouseOver($index)>{{x.year}}</p>
</div>
```

```js
$scope.mouseOver = function(idx) {
    var x = arr[idx];
    console.log(x.year);
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Special variable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#overview)

---

## `ng-mouseover` with `$event`

Directives like `ngMouseover` and `ngFocus` expose a `$event` object within the scope of that expression. The object is an instance of a [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) when jQuery is present or a similar `jqLite` object.

```html
<div id="fred" ng-mouseover="mouseOver($event)">
   Ipsum lorem
</div>
```

```
$scope.mouseOver = function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.target.id);
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions - $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)